# double variable get not printed as expected

Tags: r

I'm sorry for asking this stupid kind of question, but I can't understand why double variables are not printed as double.
It seems, that they are truncated to a max number of digits which seems to be variable.
Here an example:

```
>(1234567890.123456789 -> x)
[1] 1234567890
```

Where is the decimal digits gone? 
In the RStudio Environment view the value of x is being displayed as 1234567890.123456. Why does the console output differs from the environment view, and why does it differ from the values I entered?

```
> (567890.12345678912345 -> x)
[1] 567890.1
> sprintf("%f", x)
[1] "567890.123457"
```

The .Machine settings for double are these

```
    > .Machine$double.xmin ; .Machine$double.xmax
[1] 2.225074e-308
[1] 1.797693e+308
```

and here the complete list of the .Machine content

> as.data.frame(.Machine)
>       double.eps double.neg.eps   double.xmin   double.xmax double.base double.digits double.rounding double.guard
>   1 2.220446e-16   1.110223e-16 2.225074e-308 1.797693e+308           2            53               5            0
>     double.ulp.digits double.neg.ulp.digits double.exponent double.min.exp double.max.exp integer.max sizeof.long
>   1               -52                   -53              11          -1022           1024  2147483647           4
>     sizeof.longlong sizeof.longdouble sizeof.pointer
>   1               8                16

Thanks for any support
Wasili

---

Thanks

> options(digits=20)

helped